# VueJS - Passing props to a child component

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component where I want to pass `props` to a child component. I retrieve the props from VueX with a getter `userProfile`
and pass them like this however, in editAccount component, I am getting an error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined"`:

```
<template>
  <EditAccount :profile="userProfile" :submit="saveUserProfile"/>
</template>
<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
  import EditAccount from './editAccount.vue'

  export default {
    components: { EditAccount },
    computed: mapState(['userProfile']),
    methods: mapActions(['saveUserProfile'])
  }
</script>
```

getters.js

```
export default {
  userProfile: state => {
    return state.auth.user
  }
};
```

store.js

```
state: {
    auth: {
      user: {}
    }
}
```

I confirmed that in VueJS console I have the user object returned by the getter. The object is the user that has authenticated and is logged in.

```
user:Object
  avatar:Object
  created_at:"2018-12-05"
  email:"fake_email@example.com"
  facebook_url:"https://some_url"
  first_name:"Firstname"
  hourly_rate:"10"
  id:4
  last_name:"lastname"
  linked_in_url:null
  phone_number:123123123
  rides_count:27
  twitter_url:"https://some_url"
  updated_at:"asdasd"
  username:"asdasd"
```

Component form

```
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <div class="input">
      <label for="first_name">First name</label>
      <input
              type="text"
              id="first_name"
              v-model="accountInfo.firstName">
    </div>
</form>

export default {
    props: {
      profile: {
        type: Object,
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        accountInfo: {
          firstName: this.profile.first_name,
          lastName: this.profile.last_name,
          phoneNumber: this.profile.phone_number,
          facebookUrl: this.profile.facebook_url,
          twitterUrl: this.profile.twitter_url,
          linkedInUrl: this.profile.linked_in_url,
          hourlyRate: this.profile.hourly_rate,
          avatar: ''
        }
      };
    },
   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you fetch the user data asynchronously? Because if that's the case your `userProfile` getter is probably initially returning `undefined` until the async method returns. A simple fix would be to specify an empty object as a default value for the `profile` prop: `default: () => ({})`

Comment: No, I have the user object stored in VueX state: `state: { auth: { user: { here is the user object }}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `userProfile` is a part of the `getters` so you should be using `mapGetters` instead of `mapState`.

Change `computed: mapState(['userProfile'])`

to `computed: mapGetters(['userProfile'])`.